# Visual Studio Creation / Configuration on AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have Visual Studio project source code which has been deployed into AWS cloud, but code is being managed on individual team members' machine. But I need to manage my source code also on Cloud to make the code secured and make sure nobody can copy / paste the code anywhere else. Could you please let me know how can I configure the Visual Studio in my EC2 Server and give access to my designers / developers?

Thank you all for your support in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "managed" here? It will be great if you explain clearly what you want to achieve. Now it's not clear if you ask how to store sources or how to configure IDE on Cloud machine. Also I don't understand why you need to setup IDE on the server. Whole question is full of ambiguous words.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, my project source code (.Net & MVC Code) is on team members' local machines and being deployed to AWS EC2 servers. But I need to transfer entire the source code to EC2 servers in AWS where I have Visual Studio 2017 installed and manage the code and changes on AWS directly. So I need my team to connect to AWS EC2 servers going forward to design and implement the rest of the code rather than using their local machines. Please advise, what is the best and optimized solution?

Thank you.